How to generate mermaid ERD diagram from existing database using maven?
I want to add mermaid ERD diagram to the project documentation but it needs to update automatically whenever schema changes.
Database schema is defined using liquibase and I am using maven for build.
During build and test docker image with database (postgresql) is started and all liquibase changes are applied there, so it should be possible to generate ERD from running database or from liquibase script.
I know, there are tools like Mermerd or SchemaCrawler but I cannot find any maven plugin that can integrate them.
Here is how I am starting the dockerised database during tests:
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.codehaus.gmaven</groupId>
                <artifactId>groovy-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>${maven-groovy-plugin.version}</version>

                <dependencies>
                    <dependency>
                        <groupId>org.testcontainers</groupId>
                        <artifactId>postgresql</artifactId>
                        <version>${testcontainers.version}</version>
                    </dependency>
                </dependencies>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>execute</goal>
                        </goals>
                        <phase>generate-sources</phase>
                        <configuration>
                            <source>db = new org.testcontainers.containers.PostgreSQLContainer(
                                    "postgres:15.1")
                                    .withUsername("${db.username}")
                                    .withDatabaseName("postgres")
                                    .withPassword("${db.password}");

                            db.start();

                            project.properties.setProperty('db.url', db.getJdbcUrl());</source>
                        </configuration>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>


what about schemacrawler maven plugin?

it generates png or svg, not mermaid, but still something

schemacrawler supports mermaid afaik. Try to reach developer or find out yourself if it works in plugin

this can be done by script see: https://www.schemacrawler.com/diagramming.html with options --command script --script-language python --script mermaid.py but I cannot see an option to run it from the plugin, but it may be an option to contact developer or extend it on myown

BTW: I found also github action that does similar thing https://gitlab.com/sualeh/schemacrawler-action-usage-example but still from static db

Thanks to suggestion from @bilak I added schemacrawler maven plugin with following configuration
<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.codehaus.gmaven</groupId>
            <artifactId>groovy-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <!-- plugin configuration from question -->
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>us.fatehi</groupId>
            <artifactId>schemacrawler-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>16.21.2.2</version>
            <configuration>
                <url>${db.url}</url>
                <user>${db.username}</user>
                <password>${db.password}</password>
                <command>schema</command>
                <infolevel>maximum</infolevel>
                <title>Database Schema</title>
                <!-- <schemas>PUBLIC.BOOKS</schemas> -->
                <outputfile>database-schema.svg</outputfile>
                <outputformat>svg</outputformat>
                <config>../schemacrawler.config.properties</config>
                <loadrowcounts>true</loadrowcounts>
                <loglevel>OFF</loglevel>
            </configuration>
            <dependencies>
                <!-- If you do not have Graphviz installed, provide a dependency
                  on
                graphviz-java -->
                <dependency>
                    <groupId>guru.nidi</groupId>
                    <artifactId>graphviz-java</artifactId>
                    <version>0.18.1</version>
                </dependency>
                <dependency>
                    <groupId>org.graalvm.js</groupId>
                    <artifactId>js</artifactId>
                    <version>22.1.0</version>
                </dependency>
                <!-- IMPORTANT: Make sure you have a dependency on the JDBC driver.
                In this example, we are using SQLite as our database server. -->
                <dependency>
                    <groupId>org.postgresql</groupId>
                    <artifactId>postgresql</artifactId>
                    <version>42.6.0</version>
                </dependency>
                <!-- IMPORTANT: Make sure you have a dependency on the SchemaCrawler
                plugin. In this example, we are using SQLite as our database server. -->
                <dependency>
                    <groupId>us.fatehi</groupId>
                    <artifactId>schemacrawler-postgresql</artifactId>
                    <version>16.21.2</version>
                </dependency>
            </dependencies>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <id>generate-schema</id>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>schemacrawler</goal>
                    </goals>
                    <phase>generate-sources</phase>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>
        <!-- other plugins -->
    </plugins>
</build>

It's important that the schemacrawler plugin goes after the groovy-maven-plugin
It generates diagram in SVG or PNG format - still not mermaid, but always something.
